# Pencil-like functionality

Tags: d3.js

I've been searching around for a way to use D3 and a hand drawn pencil like capability. Is this something that is doable? I've looked around the different examples on mbostock site, but couldn't find anything that allowed you to manually draw within the zoomable area.

Comment: Do you look for something like this: [http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592) ?

Comment: I want something where you can manually draw on the d3 container. Like free hand drawing. That would be zoomable within the d3 container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like @coolblue's solution but here's an alternative.  It uses a path element to really feel like drawing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 1000)
      .attr('height', 1000);
      
    var color = d3.scale.category20();
    
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis");
    
    var drawObj = {
      isDown: false,
      dataPoints: [],
      currentPath: null,
      color: 0
    }
    
    svg.on("mousedown", function(){
      drawObj.isDown = true;
      
    });
    svg.on("mousemove", function(){
      if (drawObj.isDown){
        drawObj.dataPoints.push(
          [d3.event.x, d3.event.y]
        );
        if (!drawObj.currentPath){
          drawObj.currentPath = svg.append("path")
            .attr("class","currentPath")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .style("stroke",color(drawObj.color))
            .style("fill", "none");
        }
        drawObj.currentPath
          .datum(drawObj.dataPoints)
          .attr("d", line);
      }
    });
    svg.on("mouseup", function(){
      drawObj.isDown = false;
      drawObj.currentPath.attr("class","oldPath");
      drawObj.dataPoints = [];
      drawObj.currentPath = null;
      if (++drawObj.color > 19) {
        drawObj.color = 0;
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dvf61WNz6HbVtNgOWvjs?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much for your work! This is what i need. I really appreciate your help Mark

Comment: @scott, now you've got me thinking about recreating MS Paint in `d3`.  There's a time waster...

Comment: @Mark that'd be seriously cool! Or maybe [Mac Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPaint), with the original low-res interface, the quadratic curve tool and the fill patterns! With today's resolutions you'd have to make each pixel 2x2 or even 3x3 rectangles. I remember spending hours at an original Macintosh when I was 6, doodling with Mac Paint. That was before [Windows 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_1.0) which was a complete copycat—which I also played with. Ah the memories!

Comment: As for the answer itself, I think you should add some smoothing to the path. It feels a bit too angled right now. Good work though!

Comment: plus 1 from my daughter! I just copied this into my post and added touch support @Mark :)

Answer (score 5):

This might be OK to get going...
(it's a modified particle pattern with gravity, charge and friction set to zero)

```js
;(function() {
      var w = 900, h = 400, nodes = [], touch,

          svg = d3.select("#vizcontainer").append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h),

          force = d3.layout.force()
          .size([w, h])
          .gravity(0)
          .charge(0)
          .friction(0),

          outputDiv = d3.select("body").insert("div", "#vizcontainer").attr("id", "output").attr("class", "output"),
          touchesDiv = d3.select("body").insert("div", "#output").attr("id", "touches")
          .style("margin-right", "10px").attr("class", "output");

      force.on("tick", function (e) {

        outputDiv.text("alpha:\t" + d3.format(".3f")(force.alpha())
          + "\tnodes:\t" + force.nodes().length)

        svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
      });

      svg.on("mousemove", onMove);
      svg.on("touchmove", onTouch);
      svg.on("touchstart", onTouch);

      function onMove() {
        updateMethod.call(this)
      }
      function onTouch() {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        updateMethod.call(this)
      }

      function idiomatic() {
        force.nodes(nodes);
        return function () {
          var pointM = d3.mouse(this), pointT = d3.touches(this),
              point = pointT.length ? pointT[0] : pointM,
          node = { x: point[0], y: point[1] };

          nodes.push(node);

          svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("r", 3)
          .each((function (n) {
            return function (d, i) {
              var i = nodes.indexOf(n);
              nodes.splice(i, 1)
            }
          })(node));

          force.start();
        }
      } /*idiomatic*/


      updateMethod = idiomatic();
    })()
```

```css
body, html {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
  }
    #vizcontainer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

   svg {
      outline: 1px solid red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .output {
      pointer-events: none;  
      display: inline-block;
      z-index: 1;
      margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="vizcontainer"></div>
```

Trying to get touch going on Mark's solution...

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 1000)
      .attr('height', 1000);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var line = d3.svg.line();

    var drawObj = {
      isDown: false,
      isTouched: false,
      dataPoints: [],
      currentPath: null,
      color: 0
    }

    svg.on("mousedown", function () {
      drawObj.isDown = true;
    });

    svg.on("mousemove", function () {
      if (drawObj.isTouched) {
        lift(); drawObj.isTouched = false
      };
      draw.call(this);

    });

    svg.on("touchmove", function () {
      d3.event.preventDefault();
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
      drawObj.isDown = drawObj.isTouched = true;
      draw.call(this);
    });
    svg.on("touchstart", function () {
      if (drawObj.isTouched) {
        lift(); drawObj.isTouched = false
      };
    })


    function draw() {
      if (drawObj.isDown) {
        var pointM = d3.mouse(this), pointT = d3.touches(this),
            point = pointT.length ? pointT[0] : pointM,
            node = { x: point[0], y: point[1] };

        drawObj.dataPoints.push(
          [node.x, node.y]
        );
        if (!drawObj.currentPath) {
          drawObj.currentPath = svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "currentPath")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .style("stroke", color(drawObj.color))
            .style("fill", "none");
        }
        drawObj.currentPath
          .datum(drawObj.dataPoints)
          .attr("d", line);
      }
    };
    svg.on("mouseup", lift)
    function lift () {
      drawObj.isDown = false;
      drawObj.currentPath && drawObj.currentPath.attr("class", "oldPath");
      drawObj.dataPoints = [];
      drawObj.currentPath = null;
      if (++drawObj.color > 19) {
        drawObj.color = 0;
      }
    }
```

```css
svg {
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Cool Blue, for the starting point. I appreciate you taking the time to look into this.